# Inverting (Negative) all the colours of Form C#

Tags: c#, colors

I have a GUI Application which has lot of colours like Green, Red, White, Brown -- All this on a Black Background.

I want to add a Screenshot button to this App. I coded it (And it works fine) but I have to give a visual indication to user about the Screenshot is taken (NOT By any MessageBox).

One of the Best Method I could think was to invert all the colours for a moment and get back to normal (Like a Snapshot in Adobe Reader).

Can anyone help me with this?

Or with any other idea by which you think Screen shot can be confirmed.

Or even Can you tell me How to "Repaint" the entire window?

I need a clue from which I could start my exploration! :(

Thanks in Advance!

**Update**: As Temp soultion, On even of Capture button, I did this:-

```
   this.BackColor = Color.White;  // My Original BackColor is Black
   Update();
   Refresh();
   Thread.Sleep(250);  // I don't want responsive UI... It's like Still Picture frame. :)
   this.BackColor = Color.Black;  // Back to Normal
   Update();
   Refresh();
```

Comment: Could always flash the screen white and fade back to the picture, like a camera flash (and iPhone)

Comment: @Ben How to Do that in C# is the question buddy!! I don't know how to "Repaint" the Window in C#

Comment: To do Bens idea create an empty form (BorderStyle = None, WindowState = Maximized, Opacity = 50%, BackColor = White). You can then simply show it and then hide it.

Answer (score 5):

I had similar task in my project, but i wanted to make my application GUI grayscale when connection is lost. 
I'd like to suggest you three steps:

1. Take a screenshot of your application
2. invert it
3. show this screenshot in transparent fader form over your window.

Some how-to's for each step:

1. Taking screenshot (code supposed to be placed inside your main window):

   ```
   Point lefttopinscreencoords = this.PointToScreen(new System.Drawing.Point(0, 0));
   Bitmap bg = new Bitmap(this.Width, this.Height);
   this.DrawToBitmap(bg, new Rectangle(0, 0, bg.Width, bg.Height));
   ```
2. Transform image (here is converting to grayscale):

   ```
   ColorMatrix cm = new ColorMatrix(new float[][]
                                               {
                                                   new float[] {0.3f, 0.3f, 0.3f, 0, 0},
                                                   new float[] {0.59f, 0.59f, 0.59f, 0, 0},
                                                   new float[] {0.11f, 0.11f, 0.11f, 0, 0},
                                                   new float[] {0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0},
                                                   new float[] {0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0},
                                                   new float[] {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1}
                                               });
   Bitmap BogusBackground = new Bitmap(this.Width, this.Height);
   ImageAttributes imageAttributes = new ImageAttributes();
   imageAttributes.SetColorMatrix(cm);
   Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(BogusBackground);
   g.DrawImage(bg, new Rectangle(0, 0, BogusBackground.Width, BogusBackground.Height),
               0,0,
               bg.Width,
               bg.Height,
               GraphicsUnit.Pixel, imageAttributes);
   g.Dispose();
   ```
3. Excellent form fader you can find here: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/notanotherformfader.aspx?msg=1980689 . Now, if you create a derived form (from FormFader) named SplashForm , you can do something like this:

   ```
   SplashForm sp = new SplashForm();
   sp.BackgroundImage = BogusBackground;
   sp.BackgroundImageLayout = ImageLayout.Stretch;
   sp.FadeOnLoad = false;
   sp.FadeOnClose = true;
   sp.FadeOpacity = 1;
   sp.Location = this.Location;
   sp.Height = this.Height;
   sp.Width = this.Width;
   sp.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.Manual;
   sp.Show();
   sp.Close();
   ```